# Mac OSX Screen Sharing: Does the remote screen display my actions?

Tags: macos, remote-access, remote-desktop

During my work-from-home days, I use a Mac Mini at home to access my Mac workstation in my office through a VPN set up by my IT department at work.
When I use OSX's Screen Sharing at home to control my workstation, does my workstation in my office display what I'm seeing & doing on the screen share at home, or is the screen still blank? If someone is in my office, can they see what I'm doing?

Comment: It's easy to answer this question just by using screen sharing to yourself on your own two devices. Anyway, it's not a _programming_ matter. This is a programming forum. This kind of thing goes on SuperUser or AskDifferent.

Comment: True. Sorry for that.

Comment: The thing isn't being sorry, the thing is don't do it. Don't accept an answer; just delete the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming your remote workstation's monitor is turned on, everything you do remotely is visible on that monitor and anyone physically present there will be able to see what you are doing.